# Django form get changed fields

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to see the changed data and if any field is changed, I want to mail it to an admin email.

Here is my code:

```
def send_change_email(changed_data, cleaned_data, merchant):
    changed_stuff = {}
    for key in changed_data:
        changed_stuff[key] = cleaned_data[key]
    rendered = render_to_string('model_change.txt', {'changed_stuff':changed_stuff, 'merchant':merchant })
    send_mail('Model Change!', rendered, 'no-reply@mysite.com', ['hi@test.com'])    

class FooForm(forms.Form):
    field_1 = forms.CharField()
    field_2 = forms.CharField()

    def clean(self): # Here I test if any field is changed, if so, mail to them
        if self.is_valid() and self.changed_data:
            send_change_email(self.changed_data, self.cleaned_data, None)
        return self.cleaned_data
```

The issue is, I always get the full list of fields when I try `self.changed_data`. How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: Would it not make more sense to send an email when the data is saved in the db, not changed in the form? Looks like a spam machine to me..;-)

Comment: `changed_data` is relative to `initial` in Django, the value of each field when the user is presented the form. You can supply `initial` when you instantiate your Form (and Django will automatically do this for you for `ModelForm`s if the object already exists). If you don't supply `initial`, all fields will be considered changed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could give this [snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2290/) a try, and if your problem persists you might have an issue with initializing or submitting your form.

Comment: The former link is no longer active.

Comment: If you use it on a model form it works properly, I tested that out. self.changed_data included only fields that have changed. The only one I had issue with was the FileBrowserField (django-filebrowser) which seemed to report as changed every time.